# Nonlinear differential equations in MATLAB?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

This problem seem to be difficult for me, because i just know how to resolve simple linear differential equations in MATLAB?

$\left\{\begin{matrix} \ddot{z} = 2p + 3 & \\  p = \dfrac{1}{1+z}[1- pz\left(p^{-1.2} - p^{-1.3}\right)-3p\dot{z}]& \end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: Have a look into the `ode` functions... https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: What is with the exponents, is that lists and what do they mean or is that decimals with comma instead of dot?

Comment: oh sorry, it's dot, of course.

Comment: Please explain the problem more fully.  Is $p$ a parameter?  Is $z$ the unknown function?  What is it a function of?  What domain do you seek a solution for?  Is there an initial condition?

Comment: Are you asking for advice on how to do it in MATLAB or are you asking in general?

Answer (score 1):

If you write $w=\dot z$ then you get the system
\begin{align}
\dot w&=2p+3\\
\dot z&=w\\
0&=(1+z) p - [1- pz\left(p^{-1.2} - p^{-1.3}\right)-3pw]
\end{align}
which is a differential-algebraic equation, in all probability of index $1$, as it has the form of an explicit index-1 system.

Thus you need to use one of the DAE solvers resp. DAE-capable ODE solvers that are presenton, in all probability of index $1$, as it has the form of an explicit index-1 system.

Thus you need to use one of the DAE solvers resp. DAE-capable ODE solvers that are present in Matlab.